# I need to extract a line from the text with batch for ngrok link

Tags: batch-file, hyperlink, extract, ngrok

I need to generate a ngrok link and show only the link with batch.

I have downloaded the web "localhost/4040/api/tunnels". I think of getting the page source. But I got this:

```
{"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","ID":"7769cea7b2843d7ded705c62afde8dd3","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://32a6-203-89-122-249.ap.ngrok.io","proto":"https","config":{"addr":"http://localhost:4040","inspect":true},"metrics":{"conns":{"count":0,"gauge":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0},"http":{"count":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0}}}],"uri":"/api/tunnels"}
```

Now I need to extract the public_url and the link. What can I do to extract it? The link can be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "line={"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","ID":"7769cea7b2843d7ded705c62afde8dd3","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://32a6-203-89-122-249.ap.ngrok.io","proto":"https","config":{"addr":"http://localhost:4040","inspect":true},"metrics":{"conns":{"count":0,"gauge":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0},"http":{"count":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0}}}],"uri":"/api/tunnels"}"
SET "line=%line:[=%"
SET "line=%line:{=%"
SET "line=%line:]=%"
SET "line=%line:}=%"
SET "line=%line:":"=","%"
SET "line=%line:":=",%"
SET "public_url=undefined"
SET "assign_next="
FOR %%e IN (%line%) DO (
 ECHO %%e
 IF DEFINED assign_next SET "!assign_next!=%%~e"
 IF DEFINED %%~e (SET "assign_next=%%~e") ELSE (SET "assign_next=")
)
ECHO ------------------------
SET public_url
GOTO :EOF
```

No idea where the data line you've used as an example is stored, so I've assumed it's in an environment variable `line`.

As for what you mean by `the link` - you could have specified which field you mean, or perhaps you mean the link specified as the data item `public_url`.

So - assuming your data is in `line`, use string-replace to delete `{`, `[`, etc. by replacing by *nothing*, then each `":"` by `","` and follow the bouncing ball...

Set the name(s) of the field(s) required to `undefined` (just a meaningful string, nothing magic) and process `line` with a simple `for` loop as a sequence of possibly-quoted tokens separated by commas.

The `echo %%e` command is simply for show to allow the token being evaluated to be seen.

`assign_next` is "set" to *nothing* before the `for` loop, so it will start as *not defined*

If a token matches a defined variable, then the next token contains the desired data, so set `assign_next` to the **name** of the variable to which to assign the next token.

If `assign_next` is defined, then assign the current token to the variablename contained in `assign_next`.

... and display results using `set`.